# Sendmail heredoc doesn't parse subject when running in a script

Tags: bash, sendmail

I'm running the following command:

```
sendmail [myself for testing] <<EOF
SUBJECT:New packages are available
[machine][directory] has new files for deployment.
EOF
```

If I run it in the shell, it works and sets the subject correctly. However if the same command (copy-pasted) is run in a script, the entire heredoc is put into the body, and the email is sent with no subject.

Is there something different about a script environment that would cause this to happen?

Edit - as noted in the comments, there was indentation in the bash script. The original bash script was:

```
sendmail [myself for testing] <<EOF
    SUBJECT:New packages are available
    [machine][directory] has new files for deployment.
EOF
```

The fix was to both add a `-` to the EOF and also add a newline after the subject:

```
sendmail [myself for testing] <<-EOF
    SUBJECT:New packages are available

    [machine][directory] has new files for deployment.
EOF
```

Comment: The issue is likely unintended indentation in the bash script. Try adding a `-` before the starting heredoc delim ie `-EOF`.

Comment: We ask that code in questions be a [mcve] -- the shortest thing that can be run *without modifications* to see the same behavior. There's no way your code works exactly as currently written under any circumstances (w/o a blank line between header and body, f/e).

Comment: @sjsam, ...eh? The OP isn't showing any indentation at all, and I'm not aware of any differences in heredoc interpretation between interactive and scripted environments even if so. Was there an edit within the grace period that isn't currently showing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sjsam was right, the bash script did have indentation. What I posted did run, but did require a newline as you stated in order to get the body of the email to send properly as well

Comment: @BrydonGibson, ...please [edit] the question to include all essential elements (indentation included) to allow precise reproduction.

Comment: Note that `<<-EOF` only works if your indentation uses literal tabs, not spaces.

Comment: ...that said, if combining the comments completely addresses your problem, then the question statement as a whole was false -- the claim was that you were doing different things between interactive and scripted cases, but none of the behavior involved in fixing the problem (either the need for a newline between header and body, or the need to use `<<-EOF` if you want to have tab-indented heredoc contents) is script-specific; both of these could have been observed / tested against at an interactive command line (if convincing readline to let you inject a literal tab).

Comment: I agree, you're right in that regard. The issue I had and I'm intrigued that sjsam spotted is that when copy-pasting from something like vi to a command line, it seems like bash ignored the literal tab

Comment: *nod*; readline (the library bash uses for terminal interaction) will eat those in a default configuration (being as a default configuration treats tabs as a trigger for autocompletion, and thus a trigger for an action in the shell itself rather than literal text being entered) unless you precede them with ctrl+v.